# Shared files & virtual directory persmissions on IIS

Tags: iis, asp-classic

getting myself in a twist here, trying to set up a directory on one website to store a number of files that need to be accessed as include files by a number of other websites in the same server (IIS).

I've created the directory on the main website, and then virtual directories on the other websites, all with paths set to that.

www.mainsite.com/cdn/test.asp ... opens OK
www.othersite.con/cdn/test.asp ... opens the test file on the mainsite as well

But when I try to use an include (virtual or file) it can't find the test file.

Using FileSystemObject / DirectoryExists function can locate the main cdn folder, mapping the path from the virtual folders.

But it doesn't recognise the file in that folder?

Any ideas on making this work... or suggestions for a better way to do it would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Matt

Comment: can you post some of your code?

Comment: can you provide exact error info?

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but do the IUSR accounts of all your websites have read permission on the files they need.

Comment: Not too silly... that was the first thing I missed, but eventually got the permissions right for the shared folder for each of the websites/IUSR accounts.

Comment: Not really any code or error info to post sorry. The error is just a 404 if I try to access the test file via the virtual directory. The code to test is just a bit of FSO script to check if the folder and file both exist. Folder yes, file no.

Comment: Fixed it! Turns out 'include virtual=...'  works, but 'include file=...' doesn't. Had both on my test page but 'include file' was throwing an error before 'include virtual' got a chance to work. Thanks!